# i do not know why i get an OK button at the top of my list of Buttons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jscrollpane, joptionpane

I have some JButtons in a JscrollPane, in an JOptionDialog. an OK button magically appears at the top of the Buttons. I can not figure out why, or how to kill it. The top OK button does not appear if i insert the JScrollPane into a JPanel. Does any one have an idea ??

```
public int search() {
    JFrame searchFrame = new JFrame("Search Frame");
    String[] paneOptions = { "" };
    JOptionPane searchPane = new JOptionPane();
    searchPane.setMessage("");
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(searchPane);
    scrollPane.setBounds(50, 50, 200, 400);
    scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, Color.BLACK));
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    JButton Button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
    Button1.setBounds(10, 40, 150, 30);
    JButton Button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
    Button2.setBounds(10, 70, 150, 30);
    JButton Button3 = new JButton("Button 3");
    Button3.setBounds(10, 100, 150, 30);
    Button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            buttonNo = 3;
        }
    });
    JButton Button4 = new JButton("Button 4");
    Button4.setBounds(10, 130, 150, 30);
    JButton Button5 = new JButton("Button 5");
    Button5.setBounds(10, 160, 150, 30);
    JButton Button6 = new JButton("Button 6");
    Button6.setBounds(10, 190, 150, 30);
    JButton Button7 = new JButton("Button 7");
    Button7.setBounds(10, 220, 150, 30);
    JButton Button8 = new JButton("Button 8");
    Button8.setBounds(10, 220, 150, 30);
    JButton Button9 = new JButton("Button 9");
    Button9.setBounds(10, 220, 150, 30);
    JButton Button10 = new JButton("Button 10");
    Button10.setBounds(10, 220, 150, 30);

    // searchPane.add( Button1 );
    searchPane.add(Button1);
    searchPane.add(Button2);
    searchPane.add(Button3);
    searchPane.add(Button4);
    searchPane.add(Button5);
    searchPane.add(Button6);
    searchPane.add(Button7);
    searchPane.add(Button8);
    searchPane.add(Button9);
    searchPane.add(Button10);

    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 125));

    String[] options = { "OK", "Cancel" };
    int selectedOption = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, scrollPane, "The Title", 0, -1, null, options, options[0]);

    return buttonNo;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ah, it took me some time to figure out why you were getting this OK button. After copying the code and running it, I found that its normal to have that OK button on top. You are construction a new object *searchPane* of type **JOptionPane**.

```
JOptionPane searchPane = new JOptionPane();
searchPane.setMessage("");
```

if you change that code to :

```
JOptionPane searchPane = new JOptionPane();
searchPane.setMessage("This Text belongs to the searchPane instance of type JOptionPane");
```

[image]

You will still the OK button on top, but you will have the new text message on top of the button. Thats just to show you what JOptionPane does. Now to answer your question and to completely remove the OK button ( which is part of the JOptionPane ) , you need to remove the JOptionPane. In order to do that, you can modify your code to include a different component that can act as a container for your buttons. Like so:

```
JPanel searchPane = new JPanel();
searchPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(searchPane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
```

[image: No Ok Button]

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your code creates two `JOptionPane`s:

The first `JOptionPane` is created explicitly at line 4:

```
    JOptionPane searchPane = new JOptionPane();
    searchPane.setMessage("");
```

This first `JOptionPane` is created with default options, meaning the you get the default `OK` button with it.

The second `JOptionPane` is created implicitly for you at the end of your method:

```
    int selectedOption = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, scrollPane, "The Title", 0, -1, null, options, options[0]);
```

This second `JOptionPane` has the buttons that you specify (OK, Cancel)

---

To solve your problem you should use a `JOptionPane` as a container for your buttons.

Instead use a `JPanel` as container:

```
    JPanel searchPane = new JPanel();
    searchPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(searchPane));
```